# ReactJS wrapping child component in div breaks table

Tags: reactjs

ReactJS requires you to wrap every element being rendered in a parent div or element.

This breaks tables and my responsive table I'm trying to create, the individual `.cell` elements need to be inside the `.row` parent, but the enclosing div tag breaks it, see images.

Is there a workaround for this?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Don't make cells a standalone component? *"ReactJS requires you to wrap every element being rendered in a parent div or element."* No, the current limitation is that the `render` method has to return a single element. Since you are not showing your code we would have to guess how you are achieving this result. But in general, doing something like `<div className="row">{rows.map(d => <div className="cell">{d}</div>}</div>` should work just fine.

Comment: I have to switch between components inside each Item, thats why I have them separated.

Comment: That's fine, the mapping function can return whatever you want. My  point is that you do `<Row>{cells.map(() => <Cell />)}</Row>` instead of `<Row><Cells /></Row>`.